# Вылетает при выборе файла через fileChooser

Tags: файлы, javafx, scanner

Имеется кнопка, на ней действие, которое описано методом в другом классе.
При попытке загрузить файл приложение просто не отвечает,а когда я открываю окно выбора файла и нажимаю отмену в консоли идет куча ошибок, которые ссылаются на строку с try:

```
//главный класс
loadFile.setOnAction(e -> actions.loadFile(primaryStage));
//другой класс
public  void loadFile(Stage window) {
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(window);
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)){

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

    }
}
```

Comment: Приложи стектрейс, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

[showOpenDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html#showOpenDialog-javafx.stage.Window-) - возвращает `null`, если вы не выбрали файл. Отсюда и ошибка. Необходима проверка:

```
if ( file != null )
```